# sudo failing even though ownership and modes set correctly

Tags: ldap, sudo, pam

I am getting the dreaded `sudo: must be setuid root` error even though the executable in `/usr/bin/sudo` has ownership `root:root` and mode 4755 (`-rwsr-xr-x`). `/etc/sudoers` is mode 440. My user is in sudoers with all appropriate settings. I've purged and re-installed the package, to no avail.

I didn't initially configure this machine; its upkeep has fallen to me by default. Is it possible that this behaviour is an interaction with PAM and, if so, how do I fix it? The machine is running Debian squeeze 2.6.26-2-686 SMP kernel. Nothing is written on failure to `/var/log/auth.log` so it's bailing out before that.

UPDATE: here's sudoers (with a lot of superfluous comment lines removed), but I'm pretty sure it's not the issue.

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:\
    /usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification
User_Alias              SUDOERS=david
Defaults:SUDOERS        !lecture,!authenticate

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
SUDOERS ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Yes, I know this is overly lax. I'll tighten it up when I get it working. As far as I can tell, it never even gets to the stage of reading this file, but dies when the sudo process itself tries to escalate its user ID. A near-identical setup works flawlessly on several (>10) other machines, so I think it must be an external configuration that is causing this to fail.

Comment: What's the command you are trying to run? I get this with `strace sudo` as that won't take sudo's permissions into account.

Comment: I'm trying to run `sudo su`

Comment: Why don't you post your /etc/sudoers  file so we can see what's in there?

Comment: Have you tried to create another user, chmod/chown the sudo binary over again and try `sudo su -` or `su -` etc. I don't have an answer at this moment.

Comment: Firstly, are you sure you're picking up the right sudo (ie, does the error persist when you do `/usr/bin/sudo` instead of letting PATH do the work)?  If you are, could we see the output of `mount`, in case `/usr` has somehow got mounted `nosuid`?

Comment: Ding ding ding! We have a winner! The nosuid option was indeed set on the partition (no idea what the rationale was for that). Thanks MadHatter. Please promote this to an answer so I can upvote it properly. Can't believe I didn't think to check this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to MadHatter, I found the solution. The filesystem had been created as one big root partition (not by me!) with /usr, /var, /home and so on simply as subdirectories. For some reason, it had also been mounted nosuid, presumably in a misguided attempt at security. I'm promoting this to an answer so it will show up more readily for anyone suffering the same issue. I should have checked mount options but didn't think to as it's such a silly situation to encounter.